# How to save a file in parse-server?

Tags: angular, parse-server

I have a basic parse-server running with `parse-server: 2.8.4` and `parse: 1.11.1`. I have connected the server to a MongoDB Atlas cluster created recently using an `appId` and `masterKey`.

I have also created an angular app using the most recent parse SDK. I have added an `input` for files which im sending in my parseService as:

```
async onFileSelected(event: any) {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    const file = event.target.files[0];

    this.parse
      .uploadPhoto(id, 'photo', file)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('successfully uploaded photo');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

and this is the parseService function:

```
async uploadPhoto(id: string, fieldName: string, file: any): Promise<any> {
    const parseFile = new Parse.File(file.name, file);
    const Landmarks = Parse.Object.extend('Landmarks');
    const query = new Parse.Query(Landmarks);
    const landmark = await query.get(id);

    await parseFile.save();
    await landmark.set(fieldName, parseFile);
  }
```

I have other request to the parse-server to fetch, save or authorize a user and everything works fine, but when i select a file and sent it to be saved like this. I get an 400 code error from the server and the error msg: `error: Could not store file. code=130, message=Could not store file.`

I have researched a bit to find a solution, a common one was no space left in the db. My db is basicly empty and still has space and the jpegs im trying to save are not that big. I have also checked my atlas cluster and it seems like even tho i get an error, theres a collection called `fs.chunks` but when i check the parse dashboard theres nothing there.

I would prefer a solution where i dont have to change my parse-server version if it exists but any solution works with me, if theres any info i missed, ask and ill provide it.

Comment: Could you share your Parse Server configuration regarding file adapter?

Comment: i just cloned the parse-server-example and added environment variable for appId, masterKey and mognodb url

Comment: Does it work with latest version of Parse Server?

Comment: I havent tried the latest version

Comment: Ok, so i updated the parse-server to the latest and now it seems to save the file succesfully in mongoDB but like i showed in the question, im trying to save the file to a class later and its not saving it in the photo field.

Comment: Actually, i just forgot to save the class, everything seems to work great now.